# Several inputs and arguments with onInput in Elm

Tags: elm

I'm experimenting a little with Elm. Right now I have several input range on the screen and I want to control individually their values, but I don't know how to distinct between them (in Js I would send the ID and the VALUE of the input on the onInput callback) since I only can send ONE argument with the Elm's onInput

```
inp : Input -> Html Msg
inp inp =
    div [ class "input" ]
        [ p [] [ text inp.name ]
        , input [ id (toString inp.id), type' "range", value inp.volume, onInput ChangeInput ] []
        , controls inp.name inp.id
        ]

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Play id ->
            ( play model id, Cmd.none )

        ChangeInput id value ->
            -- Here I want to grab the id and the value coming from the input --

        NoOp ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )
```

Any help? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your message definition should be:

```
type Msg =
  ...
  | ChangeInput Id String
```

This gives it a signature of `(Id -> String -> Msg)`.
it takes an `Id` and a `String` and it returns a `Msg`. And the message includes id and string.

You can supply your own additional arguments by making the following change in your view:

```
onInput (ChangeInput id)
```

The formula `(ChangeInput id)` is a partial application:

You do not supply all arguments, but only one, so the result will be a function, that takes in the remaining arguments, and outputs the `Msg` type.

you already provide the `Id` to the message `(Id -> String -> Msg)`, so the remaining signature will be `(String -> Msg)`, which is what `onInput` is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

When you define a Union Type, you define both: type annotation definition and value constructor for it.

```elm
type Msg
    = NoOp
    | SomeMessage Int String
```

### Union Type annotation definition

Here you will use `Msg` to define type annotation definitions for functions like:

```elm
update: Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
```

### Union Type value constructors

Then you will use `NoOp` and `SomeMessage` as constructor functions for values of type `Msg`

Here is an example of function, which constructs a `SomeMessage` value and returns it:

```elm
createSomeMessage: Int -> Msg
createSomeMessage number =
    SomeMessage number "Hello!"

createSomeMessage 1 -- SomeMessage 1 "Hello!"
```

### Union Type value constructors with with partial application

Elm supports Partial Application, which means, you can wait with the construction of values of `Msg` type, until you have all required arguments.

Here is how it works:

```elm
-- Partially applied value constructor, which expects new argument
messageWithId : String -> Msg
messageWithId =
    SomeMessage 1

{- Later in the view, (SomeMessage 1) will wait for the String from the
   input DOM event
-}
input [ onInput messageWithId ] []

-- Alternative way to express the same thing:

input [ onInput (SomeMessage 1) ] []
```

The example above shows, how you can use value constructors to apply some arguments, before the DOM event fires. That will result in to a message with data from partially applied function and the event itself.

Here's one [example](https://github.com/halfzebra/elm-examples/blob/master/examples/generic-update/Main.elm#L106) of described technique in action.

Answer (score 1):

Use partial application: `onInput <| ChangeInput inp.id`

The resultant function being passed now takes a single string argument as expected by `onInput`.

Comment: Compiler says this:  (<|) is expecting the right argument to be a:

    String -> a

But the right argument is:

    Msg

Comment: @Trajan Can you paste the type definition involving `ChangeInput`? As @wintvelt wrote does your Msg definition contain `ChangeInput Id String`?

Comment: That was the problem, the definition :)